# TextToSpeech only works when button is pressed, not when called separately

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I tried to do something extremely simple or I thought it was.

In my BluetoothChat, I set

```
public static boolean potato = false;
```

In the onCreateBundle of my MainActivity, I have

```
talker = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
{
   @Override

     public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
              {
                 talker.setLanguage(Locale.US);
               }
         }
 });

if(BluetoothChat.potato == false)
{
  speakOut();
}
```

When speakOut(); is called by a button or separately by itself it works.

```
public void speakOut()
{
  String original ="You will have a seizure in thirty seconds.";
  talker.speak(original,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
}
```

However, this does not work. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210164/2982225

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nice to hear that. When you solve the problem, please post the [answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It will help someone in the future. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help from Payeli. Here is the solution! Place the if statement within the onInit.

```
talker = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
{
   @Override

     public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
              {
                 talker.setLanguage(Locale.US);
               }
            if(BluetoothChat.potato == false)
            {
              speakOut();
             }
         }
     });
```